# Unable to bind Json Data with Table Header using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im getting data in this format from api, but when i try binding it to table using angularjs it is creating empty space instead of values. Im also getting more then one table from some Api's please explain who to bind different datatables in different tables too. thanks

```
{"Table": 
  [{ 
    "SchoolId":1, 
    "schoolname":"Microsoft",
    "SCHOOLCODE":"29911583", 
    "WEBSITE":"JLR",
    "USEREMAIL":"faucibus@aliquamiaculislacus.org", 
    "PHONE":"841-9331",
    "ADDRESS1":"682-5760 Felis Street", 
    "ISACTIVE":0, 
    "PLANTYPE":3 
  }] 
}
```

**Angular Controller**

```
SMSApp.factory('GetStudentService', function ($http) {
    studobj = {};

    studobj.getAll = function () {
        var stud=[];

        stud = $http({ method: 'Get', url: 'http://localhost:58545/api/Student?Studentid=1' }).
            then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        return stud;
    };
    return studobj;
});

SMSApp.controller('studentController', function ($scope, GetStudentService) {
    $scope.msg = "Welcome from Controller";

    GetStudentService.getAll().then(function (result) {
        $scope.school = result;
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <tbody ng-controller="studentController">
     <tr ng-repeat="schools in school track by $index">
         <td>{{schools.SchoolId}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.schoolname}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.SCHOOLCODE}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.WEBSITE}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.USEREMAIL}}</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

**WHAT I GET**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change in your **Angular Controller** :

```
SMSApp.controller('studentController', function ($scope, GetStudentService) {
    $scope.msg = "Welcome from Controller";

    GetStudentService.getAll().then(function (result) {

   /********************* Changed Here ********************/

        $scope.school = JSON.parse(result._body); // Or only JSON.parse(result)
        $scope.school = $scope.school.table; 
    });

});
```

**And your HTML Code :**

```
 <tbody ng-controller="studentController">
     <tr ng-repeat="schools in school track by $index">
         <td>{{schools.SchoolId}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.schoolname}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.SCHOOLCODE}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.WEBSITE}}</td>
         <td>{{schools.USEREMAIL}}</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: If its work and was helpful for you, Then you can upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Naming the data `school` is confusing. Do instead:

```
GetStudentService.getAll().then(function (data) {
    $scope.tableObj = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

```
 <tbody ng-controller="studentController">
     <tr ng-repeat="school in tableObj.Table track by school.SchoolId">
         <td>{{school.SchoolId}}</td>
         <td>{{school.schoolname}}</td>
         <td>{{school.SCHOOLCODE}}</td>
         <td>{{school.WEBSITE}}</td>
         <td>{{school.USEREMAIL}}</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
```

From the Docs:

> **Best Practice:** If you are working with objects that have a unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier instead of the object instance, e.g. `item in items track by item.id`. Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.
>
> [— AngularJS ng-repeat API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Comment: can you please help me out with this

Comment: {"Table":[{"SchoolId":1,"schoolname":"Microsoft","SCHOOLCODE":"29911583","WEBSITE":"JLR","USEREMAIL":"faucibus@aliquamiaculislacus.org","PHONE":"841-9331","ADDRESS1":"682-5760 Felis Street","ISACTIVE":0,"PLANTYPE":3}]}

Comment: The answer works with that data in this [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSgf2o8czUsCogHZjI9H?p=preview). The only issue that I see is that the `ng-controller` directive is on a `<tbody>` element which is a bizarre place for a controller.

Comment: I have made the exact code changes, it is logging console. but, ng-repeat doesn't not render values still. and also i have moved ng-controller to the main div. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your result with result.Table in your controller because if you properly see your response it is inside "Table" named array. Try this you should be able to see your records

```js
SMSApp.controller('studentController', function ($scope, GetStudentService) {
    $scope.msg = "Welcome from Controller";

    GetStudentService.getAll().then(function (result) {
        $scope.school = result.Table;
        console.log(result);
    });

});
```

Note: I have replaced your API call in the jsfiddle link with the response mentioned in the question.
JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/zu8q7go6/9/

Comment: value is coming as undefined after adding ".Table" to result.